# pgAdmin can't connect to database server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Database server os = Ubuntu 16.04
client machine= Windows os 8.

we are not able to connect database server from pagAdmin which I have installed on my laptop (while its prompting for password).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured "pg_hba.conf" file in the server for remote access? IF not, you need to add following in the file

```
# vi  /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
host    all         all         192.168.101.20/24    trust
```

192.168.101.20/24 is just an example, you need to write clients IP and port.

Comment: Path- root@localhost:/etc/postgresql/9.5/main# ls
environment  pg_ctl.conf  pg_hba.conf  pg_ident.conf  postgresql.conf  start.conf

Comment: In data folder of postgres installation directory there is file "pg_hba.confg". In the end of that file there is tag of "# IPv4 local connections". Under that tag add line "host    all             all             all         md5" .

Comment: data directory is not showing in lib, kindly check in screenshot I have shared just now

Comment: I am not sure which directory are you in (ls command). but there definitely is the "pg_hba.confg" file in every postgres installation directory. You need to explore around a little bit in the directories in order to find that file